# Debugprint mysteriously causes notifications to fire

Tags: swift, nsnotifications, mpmusicplayercontroller

MRE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("SetupMusic").onTapGesture {
                setup()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    private func setup() {
        debugPrint("Requesting access")
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { permission in
            debugPrint("Setting up music player")
            let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
            musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
            debugPrint("Initial State: \(musicPlayer.playbackState)")  //MAGIC LINE!
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: musicPlayer, queue: .main) {  notification in
                debugPrint("State changed to \(musicPlayer.playbackState)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add "NSAppleMusicUsageDescription" to your .plist file with string value which describes why you need access to Media player framework.

1. Run app on real iOS device. Simulator does not support MPMediaPlayer
   framework.
2. Hit button to allow for permission.
3. Once granted you should get initial state. (Stopped/Paused)
4. Go to system music app and play something on radio.
5. Launch app again you should see state change to Playing
6. Swipe down for notifications and pause music and state will change to Paused

If the magic line is removed, notifications will not fire.
Why does it work like that?

---

EDIT:

I have now also tried the following setup code. And it still fails without the magic line

```
private func setup() {
        debugPrint("Requesting access")
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { permission in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                debugPrint("Setting up music player")
                let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
                
                debugPrint("Initial State: \(musicPlayer.playbackState)") //MAGIC!
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: musicPlayer, queue: .main) {  notification in
                    debugPrint("State changed to \(musicPlayer.playbackState)")
                }
                
                musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not reproducible for me, I do not get a notification.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thats the problem. Its suppose to send a notification

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` before you've called `addObserver`. You need to start observations first or you create race conditions where the notifications come before you start observing for them.

Generally you should call `addObserver` as early as possible, and be sure to call `removeObserver` in a balanced way. Otherwise you can get duplicates. To do this correctly, it's much easier if you create a separate ViewModel object to handle it. It's harder to maintain the notification unsubscribe token if you try to do this inside of the View. But in any case, `addObserver` needs to be first.

I would not bet on the callback from `requestAuthorization` being on the main queue. It doesn't promise that. `debugPrint` blocks on its output stream, however, so introducing it is going to have a big impacts on race conditions, like the one you've set up here.

Comment: I have edited the question with your two suggested changes (1) I called beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications after the observer was added and (2) The whole thing is now on main thread but still same problem